# Identify a device unique by jquery or PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I need to unique identify a device (PC, tablet, smartphone) in a webapp using javascript or PHP.

My scenario is:

I've a webapp hosted on "www.mysite.com" (shop in php that update products storage by a phisycal shop located in a city (example SHOP 1 - test street, 1, New York)).

When a employee inside the shop logged in 
 on a device at www.mysite.com (PC.. but it can be a tablet also....something connected to internet), it can select one from a several draw casher registered in database to use. (CASH DRAWER IS NOT REAL, ARE SIMULATED BY WEBAPP LIKE A BIG "CALCULATOR" , with button for: PRINT RECEIPT, CLOSE DAILY RECEIPT, ... )

For example i've:

CASH DRAWER 1

CASH DRAWER 2

CASH DRAWER 3

Only for FIRST login (where not is configured yet) i'd like to associate the device to a cash drawer i'll select.

So, if next day i'll login again from same device, i want drawer selected day before is already associated.

At this moment I do this using cookies with expiry date of 100 year. It work great if I use SAME browser. But if I use another brower I need to reassociate the drawer.
My question is: is there a method to read unique info about my device using javascript or PHP to save it on my sql and check default drawer to use not by cookies but by unique id device....? like MAC ADDESS.... harddisk serial...?

Comment: the IP is static or dynamic at your shop?

Comment: it's dynamic :(

Comment: What about using double login? 1 login that identify the drawer inside which the employee can login

Comment: Just save drawer information with user login information. So, whenever an employee login from any browser of any device you will know which drawer to assign. This would be the best way to do that.

Comment: The problem is that drawer is not depending by employee cause in the same day an employee can: for 4 hours stay in drawer 1, for 2 hours get another job inside shop (reorder tshirts, clean, ...) and for 2 h return to drawer (but can be drawer 1 or 2 or 3 ...it's not a rule... so only devices are assigned to drawers first time "forever")